# Angular router.navigateByUrl() not working if page is still loading

Tags: angular, auth0

I am trying to integrate [auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login) into my angular app.

Auth0 login event flow happens like below.

1. Angular page shows the auth0 login widget (The code for showing the login widget is located inside a service: `AuthService`).
2. User picks the authentication provider from the login widget (eg: login with google).
3. Browser gets redirected to the authentication provider.
4. User enters credentials in the authentication provider.
5. Browser gets redirected back to the angular site, to the configured callback URL. In my case, this is a page which shows a loading indicator (since login is still not complete).
6. A callback event gets fired from the auth0 login widget with the authentication token.
7. Inside the callback, A REST call is made to get more information about the user.
8. When the REST call finishes, `router.navigateByUrl('/home')` is called to return to home, after saving retrieved user information to local storage.

But, when I call `router.navigateByUrl('/home')`, the navigation doesn't happen. But, if I call `router.navigateByUrl('/home')` after about a 5 second timeout, the navigation happens successfully. I suspect that for the navigation to happen, browser loading should have completed when the `navigateByUrl()` call is made.

Does anyone know a way to do the navigation reliably, without using a timeout?

Following is the `AuthService` code.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    lock = new Auth0Lock(
        'my_client_id',
        'my_auth0_sub_domain',
        {
            auth: {
                redirectUrl: window.location.origin + '/auth_loading',
                responseType: 'token',
                scope: 'openid'
            }
        }
    );

    userProfile: Object;

    constructor(public router: Router) {
        this.userProfile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
        this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult: any) => {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, (error: any, profile: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    alert(error);
                    return;
                }
                localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
                this.userProfile = profile;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home'); //This only works because of the timeout
                }, 5000);
            });
        });
    }

    public login() {
        this.lock.show();       //This shows the auth0 login widget
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code. :-)

Comment: @Pengyy Updated question with code

Comment: Your code looks fine, did you get any errors while not using timeout?

Comment: @Pengyy No, I didn't get any errors. Also, the promise returned by `navigateByUrl()` doesn't result in an error either.

Comment: That sounds wired. Maybe you should reproduce your scenario with stackbliz or plunker to let others help you out.

Comment: Does it work if you put less timeout in setTimeout call? Like 10 miliseconds?

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk No. If the timeout is not sufficient, the behavior is not consistent. It sometimes work, and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Can you try remove this.lock.getProfile and put this.router.navigateByUrl to this.lock.on("authenticated" handler? just interesting whether it will work

Comment: And plunker would be great help in debugging it

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded `auth0-lock` from v10 to v11 and it works without a problem now.